# how to cleanup the temp tablespace in oracle 10g server , Please provide the steps for linux plateform

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to clean up the `Temp` table space which have datafiles
`temp01.dbf` and `temp02.dbf`, so please suggest me should I drop
`temp01.dbf` file  or drop the temp tablespace. Datafiles of `Temp` tablespaces is given below

```
33G     temp01.dbf
1.5G    temp02.dbf
```

Comment: Define "clean up"?  Do you want to shrink the data files?  If so, why?  Is there some reason to believe that they won't just grow back to their current size?  Growing and shrinking data files is not particularly efficient.

Comment: @Justin Cave thank you very much for responding, no i don't want to shrink datafiles, i want to drop. is it possible? i am new  but i want to free  33G size. because i need space  so please suggest how to clear the temp , without effecting anything in DB on server lavel, can anyone provide me commands step wise.

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  A database without a `TEMP` tablespace is basically unusable.  Is this a toy database installed on your laptop?  Or a real production database?

Comment: @Justin Cave thanks a lot. this real production database. in present time  3 GB space left on oracle server, That is why i want to release 33G size at any how,please suggest.

Comment: OK.  So then you do want to shrink the data files?  Is there some reason to believe that they won't just grow back to their current size? Growing and shrinking data files is not particularly efficient.

Answer (score 11):

1. Create Temporary Tablespace Temp

   ```
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP2 TEMPFILE  ‘/u01/app/oradata/temp01.dbf′ SIZE 2000M ;
   ```
2. Move Default Database temp tablespace

   ```
      ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp2;
   ```
3. Make sure No sessions are using your Old Temp tablespace

   ```
      a.  Find Session Number from V$SORT_USAGE: 
     SELECT USERNAME, SESSION_NUM, SESSION_ADDR FROM V$SORT_USAGE; 

      b.  Find Session ID from V$SESSION:

     If the resultset contains any rows then your next step will be to find the SID from the V$SESSION view. You can find session id by using SESSION_NUM or SESSION_ADDR from previous resultset.

     SELECT SID, SERIAL#, STATUS FROM V$SESSION WHERE SERIAL#=SESSION_NUM;
     OR
     SELECT SID, SERIAL#, STATUS FROM V$SESSION WHERE SADDR=SESSION_ADDR; 

      c.  Kill Session:

      Now kill the session with IMMEDIATE.

       ALTER SYSTEM KILL 'SID,SERIAL#' IMMEDIATE;
   ```
4. Drop temp tablespace

   ```
      DROP TABLESPACE temp INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
   ```
5. Recreate Tablespace Temp

   ```
      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE '/u01/app/temp/temp01.dbf′ SIZE 2000M;
   ```

6 Move Tablespace Temp, back to new temp tablespace

```
       ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
```

7. Drop temporary for tablespace temp

   ```
     DROP TABLESPACE temp2 INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES;
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much@anudeepks, its fine and free 33G size on server with the help your above script. so thank you again.

Comment: @AnandYadav , pls mark the answer correct if it has helped you  (click on the tick next to my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @anudeepks! Just wanna point something, in step 5 the sentence should be as follows:

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP TEMPFILE '/u01/app/temp/temp.dbf′ SIZE 2000M;
```

(Note that the filename has changed from temp01.dbf to temp.dbf). Otherwise we get an error because the file already exists, and also such file will be deleted on step 7.